# Shipping and Handling Information' tab shows 'No shipping information available' in Sales Order admin

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

For few orders, shipping description in 'Shipping and Handling Information' tab  show 'No shipping information available'.

I am using the onepage checkout.
All I've found is that some orders have an empty shipping_description column in 'sales_flat_quote_address' table, where as shipping_method column is always correct. I tried to reproduce the same problem,but till now  I haven't found any pattern yet.

[image]

Any help will be much appreciate

Comment: I am having this problem as well, except I'm in magento-community.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find the solution? Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Same issue after upgrade to 1.9.3.7. No resolution, eh?

Comment: I have also the same issue. Any solution for this?